# Calculate a conditional sum with NAs using tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm calculating sums with dplyr and I'm having this problem :

```
library(dplyr)

toto <- data.frame(
  classe = c("CP","CP2","CP2","CP2"),
  in_flores = c(1,0,1,1),
  effectif = c(10,50,20,30),
  effectif2 = c(10,50,14,NA)
)

toto %>% 
  group_by(classe) %>% 
  summarise(
    eff = if_else(in_flores>=1,effectif,0) %>% sum(na.rm = T),
    effeff2 = if_else(in_flores>=1,effectif+effectif2,0) %>% sum(na.rm = T)
  )
```

The result :
[image: classe eff effeff2 1 CP 10 20 2 CP2 50 34]

I expected to get 64 for effeff2 and not 34...
How to deal with the missing value?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: With your code you would need to redefine `+`, since 30+NA is NA in R's version of arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rowSums` function should return a vector that could be used in your `if_else` operation. It does have an `na.rm` parameter:

```
> rowSums(toto[3:4], na.rm=TRUE)
[1]  20 100  34  30
```

So it does in a sense redefine the `+` operation in the manner needed. Even inside tidyverse's redefined syntax, you still cannot use the unquoted column names in this expression:

```
if_else(in_flores>=1,
    rowSums(effectif,effectif2, na.rm=TRUE),0)  # nope ... error
```

But if you `cbind` them to make a single object, then `rowSums` is happy:

```
toto %>% 
    group_by(classe) %>% 
    summarise(
      eff = if_else(in_flores>=1,effectif,0) %>% sum(na.rm = T),
      effeff2 = if_else(in_flores>=1, 
                   rowSums(cbind(effectif,effectif2), na.rm=TRUE),
                   0) %>% sum(na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  classe   eff effeff2
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 CP        10      20
2 CP2       50      64
```

Answer (score 1):

The `na.rm = TRUE` instruction deletes the row containing `NA` values, so the sum doesn't take into account the last row, because `effectif + effectif2 = NA`. A candidate solution is replace `NA` values with `0`, only if it's okay with the context of the problem you're trying to solve.

```
toto %>% 
  mutate(effectif2 = if_else(is.na(effectif2), 0, effectif2)) %>%
  group_by(classe) %>% 
  summarise(
    eff = if_else(in_flores>=1,effectif,0) %>% sum(na.rm = T),
    effeff2 = if_else(in_flores>=1,effectif+effectif2,0) %>% sum(na.rm = T)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is easy to see why if you rewrite in this way:

```
# first: the if statement would be better be out of the summarise command:
# second: create a new column for effectif+effectif2
toto %>% 
  filter(in_flores != 0) %>% 
  group_by(classe) %>% 
  mutate(x = effectif+effectif2)

#  classe in_flores effectif effectif2     x
#   <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 CP             1       10        10    20
# 2 CP2            1       20        14    34
# 3 CP2            1       30        NA    NA

# the code bellow do the same but it seems easy to me to understand the result:
toto %>% 
  filter(in_flores != 0) %>% 
  group_by(classe) %>% 
  mutate(x = effectif+effectif2) %>% 
  summarise(
    eff = sum(effectif),
    effeff2 = sum(x, na.rm = T). # x is only 34 for CP2, see table above
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !